# Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'remove'

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am creating a Cordova hybrid app. I use the Facebookconnectplugin and show up a tutorial on first start. This works for every Supported Plattform and Version (Android / iOS) but not for Android 4.1
Here the code breaks with "Object # has no method 'remove'". It Breaks all the time at the line when I try to remove the fadeMe div. As said works everywhere else (Android 4.3+ / iOS 7+)

```
facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"],
    function (response) {
        //check if this is startup then remove overlay
        if(document.getElementById("fadeMe")){
            document.getElementById("fadeMe").remove();//document.body.removeChild(div);
            describeTableView();
        }
    }
);
```

CSS:

```
#fadeMe{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.75); 
  width:      100%;
  height:     100%; 
  z-index:    11;
  top:        0; 
  left:       0; 
  position:   fixed;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: 300;

  webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadein 2s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadein 2s;
}
```

And it is created like this:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.setAttribute('class', 'fadeMe');
div.setAttribute('id', 'fadeMe');
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Found a similar question but without answer: [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26513130/uncaught-typeerror-object-htmldivelement-has-no-method-remove-in-android-4)

Comment: The browser probably doesn't support `childNode.remove`, consider a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove#Polyfill).

Comment: yes I copied this in onDeviceReady and for the first look this fixed it! thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove#Polyfill) does the trick:

```
if (!('remove' in Element.prototype)) {
    Element.prototype.remove = function() {
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    };
}
```